# Can't get itext Rectangle to work correctly with annotations

Tags: java, itext

I'm new to itext and I can't get my annotation icons to appear correctly.

I'm trying to create a rectangle for my annotation icon. My example is below:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(164, 190, 164, 110);

chunk_text.setAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.createText(writer, rect, "Warning", comments, false, "Comment"));        

PdfContentByte pdb = new PdfContentByte(writer);

chunk_free.setAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.createFreeText(writer, rect, comments, pdb));

chunk_popup.setAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.createPopup(writer, rect, comments, false));
```

But, the icon fails to appear or is just a small dot in the PDF.

I cant find what Im doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You create the rectangle like this

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(164, 190, 164, 110);
```

According to the [JavaDocs](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Rectangle.html#Rectangle-float-float-float-float-):

> ```
>  public Rectangle(float llx,
>              float lly,
>              float urx,
>              float ury)
> ```
>
> Constructs a `Rectangle`-object.
>
> Parameters:
>
> llx - lower left x
>
> lly - lower left y
>
> urx - upper right x
>
> ury - upper right y

As your lower left *x* equals your upper right *x*, the rectangle has a zero width. Thus, it is not surprising that

> the icon fails to appear or is just a small dot in the PDF.

Thus, use coordinates describing a large enough rectangle, e.g.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(164, 190, 328, 300);
```

---

Another issue: You add the annotation by setting it as a chunk annotation and (presumably) adding that chunk to the PDF:

```
chunk_text.setAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.createText(writer, rect, "Warning", comments, false, "Comment"));
```

This technique eventually anyways replaces your rectangle by the bounding box of the rendered chunk text. Thus, it might not really be what you want. Instead use the `addAnnotation` method of your `PdfWriter`.

---

Furthermore you add a Popup annotation which is not related to any other annotation. This does not make sense, according to the specification:

> A pop-up annotation (PDF 1.3) displays text in a pop-up window for entry and editing. It shall not appear alone but is associated with a markup annotation, its parent annotation, and shall be used for editing the parent’s text.

Using iText to build that popup-parent relation for a parent annotation `parent` and a popup annotation `popup` using

```
parent.setPopup(popup);
```

Comment: It's doing the same thing

Comment: If I do the writer.addAnnotation, nothing appears. I have to use chunk to appear at all.

Comment: @TYD *"If I do the writer.addAnnotation, nothing appears"* - before editing my answer I tested using `writer.addAnnotation` and it worked. Thus, you did something wrong beyond what you told us.